# Flask JWT : get_jwt_identity() without @jwt_required always return Non

Tags: python, access-token, flask-jwt-extended

I am building a Flask JWT extended application, and here is what I want to do :

I have and endpoint open to everyone (i.e. no decorator @jwt_required, everyone can access the link)

but if someone access this link with an authentication, I want to be able to get back his identity, something like that :

```
@bp.route('/test', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def test() -> str:
    identity = get_jwt_identity()
    print(a)
    if identity is not None:
        # do something
    else:
        # do other stuff
```

the issue is that without the decorator, get_jwt_identity always return None

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the 4.x.x version, use `@jwt_required(optional=True)`.  If you are still on the 3.x.x version use `@jwt_optional`

Comment: Hello, coming back as I have a question, I use the @jwt_optional, currently working great, but reading the flask code I found that: 
"If there is an invalid access token in the request (expired, tampered with,
    etc), this will still raise the appropiate exception."

it is possible to avoid this exception ? I want the access open to the "else" part of my function even if there is any expired token, is it possible to do that?

currently I am thinking on override the flask function, but not sure it is a good thing to do

Comment: You could use `verify_jwt_in_request(optional=True)` and catch the exceptions that were raised. In most cases this is not the desired behavior, so there isn’t a built in way to suppress those exceptions on flask-jwt-extended.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to decode custom access token on unprotected endpoint. you need to  use the `decode_token` from `flask-jwt-extended`

```
 from flask_jwt_extended import decode_token

 def post(self):
        data = ResetPassword.parser.parse_args()
        reset_token = data['reset_token']
        decoded_token = decode_token(reset_token)['sub']
```

the `sub` refers to `identity when you're creating a token from

```
    access_token = create_access_token(identity=user.get_id())
```